# Excel VBA Code, ON Variable GOTO Alternatives

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've read the data pros and cons of `ON X GOTO` statements and am well aware of the Calls and Jmp alternatives and the fact that it's considered bad practice but would like a simple alternative solution to its use. Equally (not just being lazy) but the use of extensive lines of code for each alternative seems inefficient and not as easy to read.

In essence I would like a simple alternative to the following (written in English code rather than any specific code but needed in VBA):

```
Input x

On x Goto LineA, LineB, LineC

LineA....
End

LineB....
End

LineC....
End
```

or:

```
List of alternatives (choice = 1, choice = 2, choice = 3)

Input choice

on choice someVariable = string1, string2, string3

(Remaining code which uses that string)
```

Both are very similar, bearing in mind the list could be any length and the strings could be longer, yet selected by a single statement rather then jumping to new lines of code in every specific case.

Comment: What you are requesting is a Work Order. You need to do some reading on "VBa for beginners" and "How to instantiate a variable".

Answer (score 1):

Don't ignore best practice and advice. This code is perfectly readable, and does what you need without breaking rules...

```
Sub test()

  Select Case InputBox("Enter a value")

    Case "1"
      'Do things that are specific to "1"
       Beep
      'Or better still, call a specific sub
      DoSomething1
    Case "2"
      'Do things that are specific to "2"
       Beep
      'Or better still, call a specific sub
      DoSomething2
    Case "3"
      'Do things that are specific to "3"
      Beep
      'Or better still, call a specific sub
      DoSomething3
    Case Else
      'Do Nothing

  End Select

End Sub

Sub DoSomething1()
  Beep
End Sub

Sub DoSomething2()
  Beep
  Beep
End Sub

Sub DoSomething3()
  Beep
  Beep
  Beep
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks,  My VBA education (Self taught) had missed the use of 'CASE', it hasn't now!  I can use that for both my above situations. Although it still involves new lines for each new Select Option it is relatively succinct and can be easily followed.